# Wheezing/whistling symptoms in a tortoise

Tags: health, tortoises, upper-respiratory-disease

My tortoise was wheezing for a while. I took him to the doctor, who gave him antibiotics. Everything was fine.

Now he’s wheezing or whistling again, not sure how to describe it. Should I be concerned again?

He does eat well, his humidity is up and down and he sleeps normal.

Answer (score 2):

It would be difficult to diagnose over the Internet without hearing the sound in person. But yes, a tortoise making consistent whistling, wheezing or hissing sounds while breathing could suggest its upper respiratory system infection. If there is visible slimy mucus discharge from the nose then you could be fairly sure it's an infection, but it could still be the case even without the mentioned discharge. Also you could look for other signs of infection like swollen and inflamed eyes, but I'd say excessive wheezing is enough of a concern itself to consult a veterinarian.